# USB Hard drive Not displaying Ubuntu

Tags: usb, hard-drive, ntfs, data-recovery, data-loss

I have a 2TB Verbatim USB 3 hard drive that was working fine one evening and not at all the next day. I cannot view or mount the partitions. Running "lsusb" shows that the hard drive is plugged in but the drive is not listed when I run "sudo fdisk -l". It doesn't show up under gparted or testdisk, but gnome-disks displays the drive indicating "No Media" under volumes. The drive had 1 NTFS partition. Windows 7 Home Premium shows the drive as uninitialized.

I'd like to restore the partition on the drive and recover the data.

Comment: I won't add it as an answer, but it doesn't sound like it's a partitioning or filesystem error, because then you'd simply see it as free space in Disks. Might sound like a hardware error.

Comment: @Jo-ErlendSchinstad is there a tool that can tell me for sure if it's a hardware error?

Comment: I don't know how such a software would work if the problem is a disconnect in the controller or something like that. That doesn't sound completely right either. If the disk is important to you, I would suggest sending it to professionals for repair. If it is the disk itself, then the more you use it, the more it gets damaged, so if it's an important disk, stop using it immediately and send it away.

Answer (score 0):

If it is an **Hadware error**:

Probably there is not enough five volt power in that particular USB port to spin up the drive it's self. 
Plug a powered USB hub into the port and power the hub with the included power supply and attach the drive to the hub. This will give the necessary amps to spin that big 2 gig drive.

`lsusb` is seeing the drive controller and listing it but the hard drive itself is not spinning so no drive is mounted.

Comment: @jo-erlend-schinstad was right; it turned out to be a hardware issue. I had a technician open up the drive and he was able to fix it. Thanks.